Jest + ts-jest SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in .test.tsx file
I've been stuck on this issue with Jest for almost a day. Jest keeps complaining about an import in my .test.tsx file. I find this weird because I've resolved module issues in the transformIgnorePatterns section. I've seen a couple of StackOverflow threads that seem related, but I've still had no luck.
I've been battling this for a while now, so I thought maybe I need some fresh eyes to take a look. I've added my setup details below:
// jest error
 FAIL  src/components/CountryAutocomplete.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /..../src/components/CountryAutocomplete.test.tsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runtime@27.5.1/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)

// jest.config.ts

const config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.jest.json',
      diagonistics: {
        warnOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',

    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    '^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`,

    // Handle module aliases
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', 'src/components'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    // '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': [
    //   'babel-jest',
    //   {
    //     presets: [
    //       [
    //         '@babel/preset-env',
    //         {
    //           modules: 'auto',
    //         },
    //       ],
    //       '@babel/preset-react',
    //       '@babel/preset-typescript',
    //     ],
    //     plugins: [
    //       'dynamic-import-node',
    //       '@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods',
    //       '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    //       '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    //     ],
    //   },
    // ],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '@premier/ui/dist(?!/index)/',
    'components(?!/index)/',
    'src/components/CountryAutocomplete.test.tsx',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};

export default config;

// tsconfig.jest.json

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "ES2019"]
  }
}

// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "esnext.intl",
      "es2017.intl",
      "es2018.intl"
    ],
    "checkJs": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "types": ["node", "jest"],
  "include": ["src", "modules.d.ts", "custom.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["cypress"]
}

// CountryAutoComplete.test.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { screen, render, prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/react';
import CountryAutocomplete from './CountryAutocomplete';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

describe('CountryAutocomplete', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const renderer = render(
      <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={() => {}}>
        <CountryAutocomplete
          options={[
            {
              label: 'Spain',
              value: 'ES',
              emoji: '',
              availableCategories: ['Statutory', 'Common'],
            },
            {
              label: 'Sri Lanka',
              value: 'LK',
              emoji: '',
              availableCategories: ['Statutory', 'Common'],
            },
            {
              label: 'Sweden',
              value: 'SE',
              emoji: '',
              availableCategories: ['Competitive', 'Common', 'Statutory'],
            },
          ]}
          onChange={() => {}}
          label={'Country'}
          placeholder={'Select a country'}
          invalid={false}
          value={''}
        />
        ,
      </Formik>,
    );
    console.log(prettyDOM(renderer.container));
  });

  test('It should render CountryAutocomplete component', async () => {
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('country-autocomplete'));
    // const { getByText } = within(screen.getByTestId('country-autocomplete'));

    expect(screen.getByText('Spain')).toBeInTheDocument();
    
  });
});


Remove src/components/CountryAutocomplete.test.tsx from jest.config.ts
